# Тонкости пагинации

Tags: php, html, css

Я сделал пагинацию на своем сайте с помощью PHP, но не могу понять два вопроса (уже весь вечер убил на это). Вопросы сложные.

[image]

Буду очень рад если кто-нибудь подскажет решение.

1. Как мне сделать когда я нахожусь на странице localhost/users.php?page=1, чтобы 1 на пагинации была не активна и так далее?...
2. Как реализовано на ХабраХабре, что при клике сочетаний клавиш Alt+→ переходим на следующую страницу, а при клике на сочетаний клавиш Alt+← переходим на предыдущую страницу? (Причем хочу заметить данное сочетание клавиш работает во всех браузерах!)

Вообщем хочу сделать пагинацию как на Хабре только в своем стиле.

Comment: 1. Надо код смотреть
2. Javascript

Comment: Ну так когда конструируете пагинатор, делаете проверку - если текущая страница == текущий url в loop - вместо ссылки делаем обычный текст.

Comment: А можете подробнее расписать как сделать такую проверку, потому как я не смог нагуглить как её реализовать((

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
// ВЫВОД ПАГИНАЦИИ

// количество записей, выводимых на странице
$per_page = 10;

// получаем номер страницы
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = intval($_GET['page'] - 1);
} else {
    $page = 0;
}
// вычисляем первый оператор для LIMIT
$start = abs($page * $per_page);

// составляем запрос и выводим записи
// переменную $start используем, как нумератор записей.
echo ("\t<h1 align=\"center\">Список зарегистрированных пользователей</h1>\n");
echo ("<div class=\"container\">");
echo ("\t<table class=\"table table-striped table table-bordered\">\n<thead>\n");
echo ("\t\t<tr>\n\t\t<th>№</th><th>Логин</th><th>Email</th><th>Хэш Пароля</th>\n\t\t</tr>\n</thead>\n<tbody>\n");

$sql = "SELECT id, username, email, password FROM users LIMIT $start,$per_page";
$result = mysql_unbuffered_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo ("\t\t<tr>\n");
    echo ("\t\t<td>\n" . $row['id'] . "</td><td>\n" . $row['username'] . "</td><td>\n" . $row['email'] . "</td><td>\n" . $row['password'] . "</td>\n");
    echo ("\t\t</tr>\n");
}

echo ("\t</tbody>\n</table>\n<br>\n");
echo ("</div>");

// дальше выводим ссылки на страницы:
$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM users";
$result = mysql_unbuffered_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row        = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$total_rows = $row[0];

$num_pages = ceil($total_rows / $per_page);
echo ("<div align=\"center\" class=\"pagination\">");
echo ("<ul>");

$prev = abs($_GET['page'] - 1); // Предыдущая страница
$next = $_GET['page'] + 1; // Следущая страница

if ($prev !== 0) { // Предыдущая страница
    echo ("<li><a href=" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?page=' . $prev . "><<</a></li>");
} else {
    echo ("<li class=\"disabled\"><a href=\"#\"><<</a></li>");
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_pages; $i++) {
    echo ("<li>");
    echo ('<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . "</a>\n");
    echo ("</li>");
}

if ($next <= $num_pages) { // Следущая страница
    echo ("<li><a href=" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?page=' . $next . ">>></a></li>");
} else {
    echo ("<li class=\"disabled\"><a href=\"#\">>></a></li>");
}

echo ("</ul>");
echo ("</div>");
// КОНЕЦ ПАГИНАЦИИ

?>
```